# Python urllib2 with headers not working

Tags: python, http-headers, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to scrape a page for a certain url and I am using BeautifulSoup to do so, with a request from urllib2. The problem I am having right now is that it sends a different url to my python client than my browser. So I went around and had a look at the header requests and tried my best to imitate them to make it appear as though my python client is a real browser to no avail.

Basically:

Browser: ThisIsARealUrlToDocuments.doc
Python:  ThisIsADummyForNonHumans.doc

I should also mention that if I refresh the url in my browser then run the python script it downloads successfully a single time, then it will give me the dummy until I refresh the page.

I'm not exactly a veteran at anything web so help would be appreciated.

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36')
req.add_header('Referer', url_to_open)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

# Dummy video url always contains 779de9061
if '779de9061' in soup.find("div", {'id':'divDownload'}).a['href']:
    return "Failed to get valid video link."
# Returns the found video link    
return soup.find("div", {'id':'divDownload'}).a['href']
```

The page I'm trying to scrape is any page with video here: http://kissanime.com/Anime/Neon-Genesis-Evangelion/Episode-026?id=5260

Right now I'm using a hacky method of just loading their page quickly in a native browser then downloading, as it seems to grant me one single non dummy download per pageload.

Comment: Please provide your Python code, and if possible, the URL of the web-page that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Can you share the headers you're providing to the web service? Chances are the web service is looking at the User-Agent header.

Comment: If possible [remove unrelated parts from you code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jgeewax I have tried changing User-Agent with request.add_header() to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

When I try the URL provided with `curl`, I get

```
$ curl --silent "http://kissanime.com/Anime/Neon-Genesis-Evangelion/Episode-026?id=5260" | grep "divDownload"
<div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 15px" id="divDownload">
```

So it doesn't look like anything weird happening from my location...

Why not look at [PyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)?

```
>>> from pyquery import PyQuery
>>> doc = PyQuery('http://kissanime.com/Anime/Neon-Genesis-Evangelion/Episode-026?id=5260')
>>> print doc.find('#divDownload a')[0].attrib['href']
http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=779de9061bfeb5d6&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=sensitive_content=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1397587987&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=45A93E092F1750C81437ED7F0A5EEB5ABFCD5611.D30926273240E4116B91E85D59FF1268D0E5D5A1&key=lh1
```

Comment: PyQuery also returns the dummy video link (id=79de9061 etc), you can see that from your example.

Comment: What is the correct link? When I visit the page you linked to, I see `<a target="_blank" href="http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=281a4ee3a1110c45&itag=35&source=picasa&cmo=sensitive_content=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1397668211&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=DE7B4250835C380399019968C3772A4F1EC5E08.BFEE8A5FE5A64F7CE76FF72AE85923CB6A19E810&key=lh1">640x480.flv</a>`

Comment: That is the correct link, the differing part is the id

Answer (score 0):

You need the cookie.

Looking at the following file should help you(Its accomplishing exactly what your trying to do)
https://github.com/HIGHWAY99/plugin.video.kissanime/blob/master/default.py